# Specify the 1st or Default Image fetched by Google+ API via OpenGraph

Tags: google-plus, metadata, google-plus-one, facebook-opengraph

I'm currently coding how meta tags work on this webapp I'm making. I'm trying to make it so that when you share any of the specific pages with special content, you you get the specific OG meta values.

This currently works perfectly for Facebook sharing. However, when I tried to share the same page/URL on Google+, the first image that it fetched was some other image that's part of the website's other elements (i.e. the navigation, to be exact). You have to select through the multiple images Google+ pulls before you arrive at the specified OG image for that page.

Any ideas on how to force Google+ to always display that specified OG image? I don't mind them being able to select through and see the other images, but the first image needs to be the image I've specifically included in the "og:image" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Google+ recommended format is Schema as described at https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

The order in which Google+ checks

1. Schema
2. Open Graph
3. Title and meta description tags
4. Guess???

it should take the information from the itemscope defined nearest to the top

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
```